# Get some string values from an object Array and add those values into an observable

Tags: arrays, angular, observable

This is the obj array

```
workflows: ProteusWorkflow[]
```

ProteusWorkflow obj looks like this

```
export class ProteusWorkflow{
    id: number;
    workflowName :string
}
```

I need to add all the workflowNames from above Array to

```
filteredWorkflowsNew$: Observable<string[]>;
```

How can I do this? Please help me out!!

I've tried this...

```
this.workflows.forEach(w => {
      this.filteredWorkflowsNew$.pipe(map(wfs=>{
        wfs.push(w.workflowName);
        return this.filteredWorkflowsNew$;
      }));
    });
```

but didn't work.

Comment: `of(this.workflows.map(workflow => workflow.workflowName))`

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm what do u mean by this comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Array.prototype.map()` operator.

> `map()` function creates a new array populated with the results of
> calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.
> Please find more details about  use of `Array.prototype.map()`
> [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
let workflows = [{id:1,workflowName:"ABC"},{id:1,workflowName:"BDF"},{id:1,workflowName:"EWQ"}];
let filteredWorkflowsNew$=[];

filteredWorkflowsNew$ = workflows.map(obj => obj.workflowName);

console.log(filteredWorkflowsNew$) // ["ABC","BDF","EWQ"]
```

Comment: No problem happy to help!